# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property when overriding the toString() method

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

I have an object with an instance variable containing a list of objects. Now I want to add a custom toString() method to my list of elements (Element has a custom toString() method, too). I tried the following and it worked in the browser:

```
class Cell {
  constructor(public id: string, public elements: Element[]) {
    this.elements.toString = (): string => this.elements.join(' | ');
  }
}
```

However when running tests with jasmine I get the error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.` when initializing a Cell.

What is the best way to get a custom toString() method for the list (instead of `[elem1, elem2, elem3]`)? Is there a way to tell jasmine that this reassignment is fine?

Comment: Are you trying to add a customized `toString` to `Array` ? It would be better to create a Class, say `ElementsList`,  constructed from an array of `Elements` and that has a tailored `toString` method

Comment: Overriding protoype is considered bad practice, you should rename your custom toString function to something else (e.g customToString, convertToString etc)

Comment: @BrunoGrieder: Yes, this is a good workaround.

Comment: @fwind Great. Let me post this as an answer if you want to close that one

Comment: @borislemke: In my case, the component displaying the objects should work with different objects. I thought that setting the toString method would be nice since it is given in every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add a customized `toString` to `Array` ?

It would be better to create a Class, say `ElementsList`, constructed from an array of Elements and that has a tailored `toString` method

(note: a simple helper function would do too)